# Bayesian Formula for multiple events

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes

I know that Bayesian Formula for A giving B is like this

$ p(A | B) = \frac{p(B|A) p(A)}{p(B)}$

In case there are multiple events B C D What will the equation be like in the simplest form of a single event in the probability
e.g. $p(A|B) , p(D|A) , p(A|C), etc.$
?

$ p(A | BCD) = \frac{????}{???}$

Edit :

I have done further research and found this.

[image]

and by simplifying this further

then

$ p(A | BCD) = p(A) \frac{ p(B|A)}{p(B)} \frac{ p(C|A)}{p(C)} \frac{ p(D|A)}{p(D)}$

does this look right?!!!

Comment: Which book did you quote here? It might be useful to add that to your post.

Comment: I need that book to site in my paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just apply the same principle:

$$
p(A|BCD) = \frac{p(BCD | A)p(A)}{p(BCD)}
$$

If you have further information you might be able to further factorize this expression, but as stated you can't simplify this any further.

edit:

As mentioned before, you cannot simplify this further without additional information or assumptions. Below, I'll give some examples of the kind of assumptions you might add and where you'll then end up.

(1) First, of all, a common assumption (for instance in the [Naive Bayes Classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)) is that $B, C, D$ are all conditionally independent given $A$. In that case, you have:

$$
p(A|BCD) = \frac{p(BCD | A)p(A)}{p(BCD)} = \frac{p(B|A)p(C|A)p(D|A)p(A)}{p(BCD)}
$$

Since $B, C, D$ are your observed features, you can consider this expression as a function of just $A$. So in the context of the Naive Bayes classifier, you would compute $p(B|A)p(C|A)p(D|A)p(A)$ for all potential classes $A$ and assign your object to the class with the highest value.

(2) If, in addition to (1) you also assume that $B, C, D$ are independent, then you can further simplify the previous expression:

$$
\frac{p(B|A)p(C|A)p(D|A)p(A)}{p(BCD)} = \frac{p(B|A)p(C|A)p(D|A)p(A)}{p(B)p(C)p(D)} 
$$

$$
= p(A)\frac{p(B|A)}{p(B)} \frac{p(C|A)}{p(C)} \frac{p(D|A)}{p(D)} = p(A)\frac{p(A|B)}{p(A)} \frac{p(A|C)}{p(A)} \frac{p(A|D)}{p(A)}
$$

and this is the formula from your book. So the expression you derived is totally correct but requires some pretty strong assumptions.

Comment: you have just replaced B with BCD.. I want to know the simplest form of the equation if possible

Comment: @Maurits you may have a typo. Should be $P(BCB|A)P(A)/P(BCD)$. And yes, asmgx, this is the simplest general form.

Comment: Thanks good catch.

Comment: @asmgx in general there is no simpler form. You need more information (usually in the form of additional assumptions) to simplify the equation further.

Comment: @MauritsM what about the book that I found that provides a simpler form? is it wrong?

Comment: @asmgx I see you added more to your question. I don't have much time right now but will update my answer. In short, the book assumes independence of the attributes $V_1, V_2,...$ which allows you to simplify. This is not "wrong", but is not always a reasonable assumption.